# generate auto increment in eclipse and testing JMETER without using database

Tags: java, eclipse, request, jmeter, sequence

I want to generate auto increment (sequence) application in eclipse without using database.Then when I call this 200 times or 300 times simultaneously , it shouldn't be the same number.

For example: result should be like this in eclipse;

```
REQUEST AT THE SAME TIME --> SEQUENCE
               1.request --> 1
               2.request --> 2
               3.request --> 3
               4.request --> 4
```

I ll test using JMETER

İf someone make this kind of project Could you please share ? or any idea how to make this? or writing function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `AtomicInteger`.  It has a `getAndIncrement` method, which works like the `++` operator for `int`, but in a thread-safe and atomic way.  So when multiple threads call `getAndIncrement` on the same `AtomicInteger` instance, they'll all get different results.

If you need more values than an `Integer` can store, there's also `AtomicLong`, which works the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I've told you what you need to include in your code.

Comment: thanks I found some codes. your answer has a good keywords to search it:)

Comment: OK, I'm glad you found something useful.  Good luck with your project.